# How to remove an empty space before full stop in print () in Python [from a specified argument]

Tags: python, printing

I have code like this:

```
firstNumber= 2;

secondNumber= 3;

resultingNumber = firstNumber + secondNumber;

print ('The sum of', firstNumber, 'and', secondNumber, 'is', resultingNumber, '.' );
```

It gives me this:

The sum of 2 and 3 is 5 .

How can I make the space before full stop disappear, i.e. how to put a full stop right after 5 (without a space) ?

I want to be this:

The sum of 2 and 3 is 5.

Comment: print ('The sum of', firstNumber, 'and', secondNumber, 'is', str(resultingNumber) + '.' )

Comment: Use `f-strings` `print(f'The sum of {firstNumber} and {secondNumber} is {resultingNumber}.' )`

Comment: Answering to karel: it does not answer the question, because sep= removes the spaces of all arguments, whereas I referred to the full stop only. Conversion to string and then  concatenation works best, which is out of topic for the paste question you referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` in Python can accept any number of arguments, and it will output all the values separated with a space by default. You can either change this separator to something else, or combine some of the output into a `string` (so you will dictate if it has a space or not), or use string formatting, or something else.

For example:

```
print ('The sum of', firstNumber, 'and', secondNumber, 'is', str(resultingNumber) + '.');
```

Answer (score 1):

Youn can use the `sep` argument:

```py
print ('The sum of ', firstNumber, ' and ', secondNumber, ' is ', resultingNumber, '.', sep='');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid using the inner workings of `print` for stuff that should be considered coding logic. Just use string formatting of some sort and pass a single string to `print`, e.g. using f-strings:

```
print(f'The sum of {firstNumber} and {secondNumber} is {resultingNumber}.')
```